# adding comment in .properties files

Tags: java, ant, properties-file

By using following block of code in `build.xml` file

```
<propertyfile file="default.properties" comment="Default properties">
   <entry key="source.dir" value="1" />
   <entry key="dir.publish" value="1" />
   <entry key="dir.publish.html" value="1" />
</propertyfile>
```

I am able to generate `default.properties` file with following file contents

```
source.dir=1
dir.publish=1
dir.publish.html=1
```

I want to know how can I add my comments in the generated file? E.g. the generated properties should have the following content:

```
# Default Configuration
source.dir=1
dir.publish=1
# Source Configuration
dir.publish.html=1
```

How can I do it dynamically using Ant's `build.xml`?

Comment: Do you require multiple comments in the properties file ? Can you edit your question to reflect where you expect these comments to be.

Comment: Yes i have edited the question and now u can see what i want...

Comment: Yes i need multiple comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Writing the properties file with multiple comments is not supported. Why ?

**PropertyFile.java**

```
public class PropertyFile extends Task {

    /* ========================================================================
     *
     * Instance variables.
     */

    // Use this to prepend a message to the properties file
    private String              comment;

    private Properties          properties;
```

The ant property file task is backed by a `java.util.Properties` class which  stores comments using the [store()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) method. Only one comment is taken from the task and that is passed on to the `Properties` class to save into the file.

The way to get around this is to write your own task that is backed by [commons properties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/howto_properties.html) instead of `java.util.Properties`. The commons properties file is backed by a [property layout](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html#getLayout%28%29) which allows [settings comments for individual keys](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfigurationLayout.html#setComment%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in the properties file. Save the properties file with the [save()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfiguration.html#save%28java.io.Writer%29) method and modify the new task to accept multiple comments through  `<comment>` elements.

Answer (score 10):

The property file task is for *editing* properties files. It contains all sorts of nice features that allow you to modify entries. For example:

```
<propertyfile file="build.properties">
    <entry key="build_number"
        type="int"
        operation="+"
        value="1"/>
</propertyfile>
```

I've incremented my `build_number` by one. I have no idea what the value was, but it's now one greater than what it was before.

- Use the `<echo>` task to build a property file instead of `<propertyfile>`. You can easily layout the content and then use `<propertyfile>` to edit that content later on.

Example:

```
<echo file="build.properties">
# Default Configuration
source.dir=1
dir.publish=1
# Source Configuration
dir.publish.html=1
</echo>
```

- Create separate properties files for each section. You're allowed a comment header for each type. Then, use  to batch them together into one single file:

Example:

```
<propertyfile file="default.properties"
    comment="Default Configuration">
    <entry key="source.dir" value="1"/>
    <entry key="dir.publish" value="1"/>
<propertyfile>

<propertyfile file="source.properties"
    comment="Source Configuration">
    <entry key="dir.publish.html" value="1"/>
<propertyfile>
<concat destfile="build.properties">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
        <include name="default.properties"/>
        <include name="source.properties"/>
    </fileset>
</concat>

<delete>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
         <include name="default.properties"/>
        <include name="source.properties"/>
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) of the `PropertyFile` task, you can append the generated properties to an existing file. You could have a properties file with just the comment line, and have the Ant task append the generated properties.