# Properties file generation with property comments

Tags: java, serialization, properties

In a Java program I have a set of key-value objects and would like to write a String with those properties (that I return as a REST service response).
Everything is fine when using `java.util.Properties`

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("prop-key", "prop-value");

Writer writer = new StringWriter();
store(writer, "## File comment ##");
```

This generates the string

```
## File comment ##

prop-key=prop-value
```

Now I would like to add comments at each property like this one

```
## File comment ##

## Property comment
prop-key=prop-value
```

But using Java's Properties this is not possible. How can I accomplish this task apart from using a StringBuilder or something like that?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding comment in .properties files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924220/adding-comment-in-properties-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been there before...and I can tell you, the [Commons Configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) project from Apache will do the job; it will allow you to write and read `Properties` files...and for your requirement, have a look at the `setComment(String key, String comment)` method inside [`PropertiesConfigurationLayout`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfigurationLayout.html).